# Sticky Table Headers on webpage

Tags: html

I've been using Codrops sticky table headers - https://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/01/09/sticky-table-headers-columns/.  Since adding SSL [https] to my cloud-hosted webpages it's stopped working.  Does anyone know of a reason why adding SSL would break Codrops sticky table headers?

Here is an example of a table that did work before but does not now:

https://realmonitor.com/grayland28/

Comment: Check the link tags and ensure the connection you're using is HTTPS. Now that you're using an SSL, you're CDN's should also be secured connections too. This would be the first thing I'd check if all you've changed is an addition of an SSL.

Comment: Thanks Nick.  My html tags look like this:  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/component.css" />

Comment: Oh, would you be able to add all of the relevant code to your question?

Comment: Found it!  Reference to an external js file that needed https.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear it! I turned my comment into an answer; feel free to accept it as correct if you think it sufficiently helped in solving your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the link tags and ensure the connection you're using is HTTPS. Now that you're using an SSL, you're CDN's should also be secured connections too. This would be the first thing I'd check if all you've changed is an addition of an SSL.